# error customer.java:12: error: '(' or '[' expected customer a = new customer;

Tags: java

I have this tutorial but i cant solve it.If got more error please tell me how to fix it because i'm new at java.This is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections; 

public class Customer
{
   public static void main(String args[]){

   Arraylist listcustomer1 = new Arraylist();``
   Arraylist listcustomer2 = new Arraylist();

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   customer a = new customer;

for(i=0;i<30;i++)
{
 System.out.println("Enter customer name : ");
name = scan.next;
System.out.prinln("Enter customer id :" );
int custId= scan.nextInt;
System.out.println("Enter number of purchases :");
int numOfPurchases = scan.nextInt;
System.out.println("Enter the city :");  
city = scan.next;

listcustomer1.add(i);

}

 int total =0,avg = 0;

  for(int i=0;i<listcustomer1.numOfPurchase;i++)
{

 total= total+numOfPurchase;

 avg = total/listcustomer1;

 if(listcustomer1.numOfPurchase<10){

 listcustomer1.remove(i);

 Collections.copy(listcustomer2,i);
}   

}


System.out.println("Customer Purchase Information ");
System.out.println("Total number of purchases from all cities " +total);    
System.out.println("Average number of purchase from all cities " +avg);

 }
 }
```

I got this error error customer.java:12: error: `(` or `[` expected    `customer a = new customer;`

Can someone explain this?

Comment: `customer a = new customer();` Missing () for constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In this line customer a = new customer; you have forgotten to write `()` replace it with `Customer a = new Customer();`

Also your class name is `Customer` not `customer`.Keep it in mind java is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid Java declaration:

```
Customer a = new Customer; // Invalid
```

Change it to:

```
Customer a = new Customer();
```

Comment: The class name is Customer, not customer.