# Getting error: ';' expected

Tags: java

**This my code**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Collections; 

public class Customer
{
 public static void main(String args[]){

 Arraylist listcustomer1 = new Arraylist();
 Arraylist listcustomer2 = new Arraylist();

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 String name,city;
 int custId,numOfPurchases;

 for(i=0;i<30;i++)
{

 System.out.println("Enter customer name : ");
 name = scan.next();
 System.out.prinln("Enter customer id :" );
 int custId= scan.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter number of purchases :");
 int numOfPurchases = scan.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Enter the city :");     
 city = scan.next();

Customer a.new Customer(name,custId,numOfPurchases,city);
listcustomer1.add(a);

 }

   int total =0,avg = 0;

   for(int i=0;i<listcustomer1.numOfPurchase;i++)
 {

   total= total+numOfPurchase;

   avg = total/listcustomer1;

   if(listcustomer1.numOfPurchase<10){

   listcustomer1.remove(i);

  Collections.copy(listcustomer2,i);
 }   

 }


  System.out.println("Customer Purchase Information ");
  System.out.println("Total number of purchases from all cities " +total());    
  System.out.println("Average number of purchase from all cities " +avg());

 }
 }
```

I got this error after i running it :

```
Customer.java:27: error: ';' expected
    Customer a.new Customer(name,custId,numOfPurchases,city);
```

Is this error for missing semicolon? I already put but the error still there.

Comment: You just asked a question for constructor syntax ()(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836140/error-customer-java12-error-or-expected-customer-a-new-customer). Why don't you learn java syntax and then proceed ?

Comment: E.g., step back and work through tutorials. Pay attention to details. Programming is very much about the details.

Comment: @user3145780 If you find any answer that solved your problem then you can accept that answer

Answer (score 4):

Remove `.` from this line and add `=`

```
Customer a.new Customer(name,custId,numOfPurchases,city);
```

should be:

```
Customer a = new Customer(name,custId,numOfPurchases,city);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Customer a = new Customer(name,custId,numOfPurchases,city);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
replace dot with equals symbol 

Customer a.new Customer(name,custId,numOfPurchases,city);
```